# Google checkout ,Database updation failed

Tags: php, google-checkout

I was download and edit the code for google checkout from google help.Here i specify murchent calculation url in my site.But that function donot work in my site.Here is my code
    function UseCase3() {
    //Create a new shopping cart object
    $merchant_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx";  // Your Merchant ID
      $merchant_key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    $server_type = "sandbox";
    $currency = "USD";
    $cart = new GoogleCart($merchant_id, $merchant_key, $server_type, $currency);

```
// Add items to the cart
$item = new GoogleItem("MegaSound 2GB MP3 Player", 
    "Portable MP3 player - stores 500 songs", 1, 175.49);
$item->SetMerchantPrivateItemData("<color>blue</color><weight>3.2</weight>");
$cart->AddItem($item);

// Add merchant calculations options
$cart->SetMerchantCalculations(
    "https://mysite.com/google2/demo/responsehandlerdemo.php",
    "false", // merchant-calculated tax
    "true", // accept-merchant-coupons
    "true"); // accept-merchant-gift-certificates

// Add merchant-calculated-shipping option
$ship = new GoogleMerchantCalculatedShipping("2nd Day Air", // Shippping method
                                             10.00); // Default, fallback price
$restriction = new GoogleShippingFilters();
$restriction->AddAllowedPostalArea("GB");
$restriction->AddAllowedPostalArea("US");
$restriction->SetAllowUsPoBox(false);
$ship->AddShippingRestrictions($restriction);

$address_filter = new GoogleShippingFilters();
$address_filter->AddAllowedPostalArea("GB");
$address_filter->AddAllowedPostalArea("US");
$address_filter->SetAllowUsPoBox(false);
$ship->AddAddressFilters($address_filter);

$cart->AddShipping($ship);

// Set default tax options
$tax_rule = new GoogleDefaultTaxRule(0.15);
$tax_rule->SetWorldArea(true);
$cart->AddDefaultTaxRules($tax_rule);

$cart->AddRoundingPolicy("UP", "TOTAL");
  // Specify <edit-cart-url>
$cart->SetEditCartUrl("https://mysite.com/google/demo/cartdemo.php");

// Specify "Return to xyz" link
$cart->SetContinueShoppingUrl("https://mysite.com");
// Display XML data
// echo "<pre>";
// echo htmlentities($cart->GetXML());
// echo "</pre>";

// Display a disabled, small button
echo $cart->CheckoutButtonCode("SMALL");
```

}

Comment: Any error messages? You say it doesn't work, but how?

Comment: No error message.I call a mail function in the file "https://mysite.com/google2/demo/responsehandlerdemo.php" ,I check payment using sandbox ,payment completed successfully.But i can't get mail.So I assume the merchent calculation donot working.

Comment: Is this problem due to my SSL certificates???

Comment: @Shin have you set error mode on? http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: My actual problem is not error reporting.I need to execute a php file after user pay through Google checkout

Answer (score 0):

Clarifications:

1. Merchant Calculations URL - as the name implies is the URL that Google will use to send a callback request for Shipping and Tax, promotions calculations. That is its purpose as documented in [Merchant Calculations API](https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API_Merchant_Calculations_API). It is part of the **Checkout Phase** (sending information to Google for checkout).
2. API Callback URL - which is **set in your account** (Integration Settings) and **not** sent in any request (unlike merchant calculations url) and is the URL Google will send Notifications to as documented in [Notification API](https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API_Notification_API). This is the API you need to implement in order to **obtain data from Google** (getting information from Google - e.g. **after checkout**)

So these urls/APIs serve different purposes.

Based on your comment:

> I need to execute a php file after user pay through Google checkout

You need to implement the Notification API (the merchant calcuations url/api is *not* what you need).